# Why does this super simple jquery not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having hard time getting this snippet to work. I have made a minimal example. You can  view it online: http://jsfiddle.net/qnnZe/ where it is **working!**

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>I am going to test right now.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
$("p").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("slow");
});
```

However, **on my server it does not work**. Here is the link to my server: http://techinf.de/sleepytime/test.html

As always, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in jsFiddle your script code is executed *after the DOM has loaded* (that's the default option, see the dropdown set to "onDomReady"), on your page it's executed before that. It would work if you wrap your code in a `ready()` handler:

```
$(function()
{

 $("p").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("slow");
  });

});
```

Comment: @pewpew Have you looked at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your click handler in a document ready function.

Try either:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").click(function () {
          $(this).hide("slow");
    });
});
```

or

```
$(function () {
    $("p").click(function () {
          $(this).hide("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It will execute before the DOM is ready. Click handlers should be added in any of the normal jQuery "ready" methods, like:

```
$(function() {
    $("p").click(function () {
          $(this).hide("slow");
    });
});
```